# why does the page display differently in IE than google chrome?

Tags: html, css, blueprint-css

Certain pages display terribly in IE generally, what is the best approach to solving these issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add [a doctype](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/), so your page is in [Quirks Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode).

Add this (the HTML5 doctype) as the very first line:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

and it should look better.

Although, changing the Document Mode manually (using Developer Tools; hit F12), it still doesn't look right. There are evidently other problems with the page.

---

The most pertinent problem (after escaping Quirks Mode) is this:

```
<body style="margin: 0; padding; 0;background-color: 4DA2CA;">
```

Internet Explorer is not showing any background colour because you forgot the `#` before the colour. (And you have `padding; 0`, with a `;` instead of `:`)

This will work:

```
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0; background-color: #4DA2CA">
```

But you shouldn't be using inline styles in the first place..

This would be better:

```
<body>
```

with CSS *in your stylesheet*:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #4DA2CA
}
```

Comment: It still looks awful even with a Doctype, fyi. (tho that does partially fix it.)

Answer (score 0):

you mean that in IE the Div's are smaller.Thats because in IE css border,margin are included in the width declared.So, if you have given a div width of 100px and a margin of 10px both sides then in IE the actual visible width of this div will be 100-10-10=80px.To solve the problem you can use child css decleration.
Considering our example if you want to show this div 100px width in both the browsers do the following

```
    .mydiv{       /*This deceleration will be understood by all the browsers*/
     margin:10px;
     width:120px;       
    }

    html>body .mydiv{  /*This deceleration will not be understood by IE browsers so other will override the width*/
     width:100px;          
    }
```

Using this you can uniform the width of your Divs across both IE and non-ie browsers

Comment: (Just to let you know, that page is being live edited. Since the question was posted, it's been updated with fixes from my answer.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pointing out the reason for each element's different way of rendering in IE, I would strongly recommend not re-inventing the wheel each time you create a new page element.

Even in modern standards-complaint browsers, CSS can be very unpredictable, so it's better to use bullet-proof snippets of code from trusted sources such as

[CSS the Missing Manual](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596802447)

[CSS the Definitive Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596527330)

[CSS Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059615593X)

Start out with working blocks of HTML/CSS and modify them to your liking and test cross-browser from there. The whole process will be much less frustrating.