# How do I change the background color of an apDiv?

Tags: css, html, dreamweaver

How do I change the background color of an apDiv? I tried using background-color: eeeeee; and it looks fine in dreamweaver but in chrome and firefox the color remains white.

http://www.sandboxes.tk/sandboxes/testproject.php

Kind regards

Pongy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `background-color: #eeeeee;` instead of `background-color: eeeeee;`.

Maybe linking to this is a little overboard, but from [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#color-units):

> The format of an RGB value in
>   hexadecimal notation is a '#'
>   immediately followed by either three
>   or six hexadecimal characters.

Modern browsers don't forgive the omission of the `#`, *unless* they are in [Quirks Mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mozilla_Quirks_Mode_Behavior) (*=bad*):

> The CSS parser accepts colors not
>   beginning with #.

Answer (score 3):

The correct CSS would be

```
background-color: #eeeeee;
```

Some browsers may forgive the omission of the #, others will not.

Comment: This actually came up yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844267/why-does-the-page-display-differently-in-ie-than-google-chrome/5844298#5844298